# Microsoft AJAX with debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-ajax

There is a couple of problems which is related to microsoft ajax and visual studio when it is attached to w3wp. When i run my site when Visual studio hasn't been attached to it microsoft ajax works fine. But when i have attached to VS and use site again it rises some exceptions in DevTools js console.
An error occured :

[image]
Update - when an error is occured v4 equals false, but when all work fine v4 equals to true.
[image]

Comment: Is this a new project or has it been copied from another machine/profile/user?

Comment: Do a "clean" and rebuild on the project.  Sometimes the debug/release folders are not fully "up to date".  Cleaning often fixed it - especially if you have multiple related projects.

Comment: it's clone from bitbucket repository, i did it, but clean and rebuild do not help me. This error occur regular.

Comment: I think when debugger is enabled VS changes ajax library version but uses other when page rendering. But how to find the problem ?